# How do I achieve this simple boxes layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following layout using only regular CSS display properties (block, inline..) not using flex or grid.

[image]

The top thing(bandeau) should have a height of 100px and horizontal margins that are 50px.

Both the left and right columns should have a width of 100px.

The footer thingy(pied) should have a height of 80px and horizontal margins of 75px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bandeau {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.menuGauche {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin: 0 0 80px 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.ecran {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.menuDroite {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin: 0 0 80px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.pied {
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandeau"></div>
<div class="menuGauche"></div>
<div class="ecran"></div>
<div class="menuDroite"></div>
<div class="pied"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I am doing this kind of layout, I try to group them horizontally, so the two columns will  be wrapped in another div. similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .main {
      background-color: black;
    }

.top {
  margin: 0 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.mid {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left-col,
.right-col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.left-col {
  float: left;
}

.right-col {
  float: right;
}

.bottom {
  margin: 0 75px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="mid">
      <div class="left-col"> </div>
      <div class="right-col"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"> </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've used float and assume a height for the middle section as it was not specified. Here is a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/WQkVqodCeDZJSER2QBTA?p=preview). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the best answer so far as you didn't use flexbox or grid display, however, I can't really use a static height for the mid section, it needs to have a dynamic height. So 500px is not really the answer. That's the only problem I have.

Comment: Sure! about the height problem, I am not sure what you specifically meant by dynamic height. But if you want it to be dynamic, I agree, you must not specify a static height. In the initial problem you stated you want to achieve a similar layout, that is why I assume a static height. You can explain your problem/scenario further in order for us to help you more.

Comment: The height should be determined by the content. So that gree area should only have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you should avoid using absolute positionning and learn  display , then float.

Nowdays display flex makes it easier.

You may also use tags which can be meaningfull for the contents they hold.

Here an example via flex:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.bandeau {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.menuGauche {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.ecran {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1;
}

.menuDroite {
  width: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.pied {
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 75px;
}
```

```html
<header class="bandeau"></header>
<main>
  <div class="menuGauche"></div>
  <div class="ecran">Play the snippet full page or play with:<a href="https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJMrgz">https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJMrgz</a>.</div>
  <div class="menuDroite"></div>
</main>
<footer class="pied"></footer>
```

Here is a tutorial (among others) to start with : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

( 101 advises : for french readers  https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/53-guide-de-survie-du-positionnement-css.html )

Comment: Thank you so much for everything.

Comment: This may be a bit too much to ask, but I was kind of hoping to not use flex display for this one, the point of that exercise was to avoid using flex or grid to solve the problem, but instead use only block and in line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `display:table` on some elements to achieve the result. so wrap your main content then display it as table.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: black;
}

.bandeau{
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 50px;
}
.content-wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 180px);
    width: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper > div{
  display:table-cell;
}

.menuGauche,
.menuDroite{
    width: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
}

.ecran{
    background: lightgreen;
}

.pied{
    height: 80px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 75px;
}
```

```html
<body>

        <div class="bandeau"></div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="menuGauche"></div>
      <div class="ecran"></div>
      <div class="menuDroite"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="pied"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I did, although it's only recorded not displayed(<15reputation).

Comment: But you can set it as the right answer :), See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers